# Django filter annotate mtm

Tags: django, orm, model, annotations, aggregate

I have a model:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    ...
    required_lessons = models.ManyToMany('self')
    ...
```

When user pass lesson, i create a record in table:

```
class UserLesson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('courses.Lesson')
    is_passed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, how i can check if user have access to lesson ?

Comment: What do you mean by "access to lesson"?

Comment: For example: we have lesson1, lesson2, lesson3 and i need to pass lesson 1, 2 to get access to lesson 3. And this lessons 1, 2 we set in required_lessons mtm field

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def has_access(user, lesson):
    completed = user.userlesson_set.filter(is_passed=True).values_list("lesson", flatten=True)
    return all([l in completed for l in lesson.required_lessons])
```

PS: not tested, adjustments may be necessary

Comment: Imagine we have a lot of lessons... How to do this with couple queries ?

Comment: I think about: get completed lessons as you wrote and then we need .annotate(completed=Count(completed)) for example. And if we have variable completed=0 then access denied. But how to do this in practice, i don't know.

Comment: Then you can do completed = user.userlesson_set.filter(is_passed=True).count()